# Why to use the $-sign and why it doesnt work for me?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

i am watching currently a course and the teacher is using a lot of the $-sign:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

const weapons = ['candlestick', 'lead pipe', 'revolver'];

const makeBroken = function(item){
  return `broken ${item}`;
};

const brokenWeapons = _.map(weapons, makeBroken);

console.log(brokenWeapons);
```

I am using instead this variant:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

const weapons = ["candlestick", "lead pipe", "revovler"]

function makeBroken(item) {    
    return 'broken ' + item;   
}

const brokenWeapons = _.map(weapons, makeBroken)

console.log(brokenWeapons);
```

But when i try to modify my version to "her" style, it doesnt work:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
    
const weapons = ["candlestick", "lead pipe", "revovler"]
    
function makeBroken(item) {    
      return 'broken  ${item}';   
 }
    
 const brokenWeapons = _.map(weapons, makeBroken)
```

The first and second give me this out and is working: [ 'broken candlestick', 'broken lead pipe', 'broken revovler' ]
The third give me this output and is not working: [ 'broken ${item}', 'broken ${item}', 'broken ${item}' ]

My questions:
Is the variant of the teacher better with the ${}-method or it is only a matter of taste?
Why is the modified variant (the third) not working?

Thanks a lot for the help of the stupid questions :D

Comment: You need to use backtick `\`` instead of single quote`'`.

Comment: You have to use the ` character in order to use variable interpolation in strings.

Comment: Well, there’s a clear difference between `'` and `\`` and the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#description) is pretty clear on this.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+template+literal+not+working) of [ES6 / ECMA6 template literals - not working](/q/37245679/4642212).

Comment: [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: Also see the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) and [statements](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you are using `'` instead of `` ` ``

For example:

```
return 'broken  ${item}';
```

Is wrong because you are using `'`

Now the rigth way:

```
return `broken  ${item}`;
```

More info about template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: To clarify the difference between ' and `, since it might not be so clearly visible for some with e.g. vision loss, the first is a single-quote mark and the other is a backtick (aka grave accent). Here's a link to the MDN-docs on template literals to go with this answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

- you need to use GRAVE ACCENT  ` instead single or double quotes